# Is it possible to prevent a node from drawing in nodetree

Tags: python, node-editor

for an addon using a custom nodetree, i would want to let the user totally hide some nodes, but without removing them.
They would still be active and execute as usual.
Is it possible through python api ? I dind't manage to find the solution so far !
Thanks !

Comment: Grouping nodes is usually what you do when you want to hide nodes but still be able to access them if needed. I'm sure it's doable with code. I don't know any other way to hide nodes.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. For the nodes to be 'active' and execute as usual they must be connected to the node tree in some way - so the sockets connecting to/from them must connect to *something*. If the requirement is to hide them *within* another node to simply make them inaccessible then you could use a Custom Node Group (NodeCustomGroup).